# Fastest way to do Array A = Array B without changing the reference of A

Tags: javascript

I have an array `A` and a function that generates me an array `B`

```
var A = ["test"];
var B = ["hello", "world"];
var C = A;
```

How to make it so `A = B` (contains all and only the values in B) without changing its reference, so C also contains all and only the values in B.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: If you set C = A first, then setting A = (Anything) won't affect C in any condition.

Comment: @remdevtec that's not quite what OP is asking. I believe he is specifically asking how to change the underlying pointer of `A` to point to `B` *after* `C` has already been pointed to `A`. So, after changing the reference, printing `C` would in fact print the contents of `B`. I'm fairly sure this isn't possible based on the quesiton/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Comment: remdevtex and Unknown users, the suggested duplicates are not duplicates. They do not apply to keeping the same array and make a copy instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
A.splice(0);
A.push.apply(A, B);
```

Splice will remove all of the items from A. Push will add the items from B to A. Except push takes an argument list, not an array, so we call apply in order to convert the array into arguments.

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/99qzfefe/).

Comment: It's not obvious what the `A.push.bind(A, B);` line is supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error, just fixed: you need to call apply, not bind.